# python create a text file with name from partial variable

Tags: python, file, variables, text, partial

I have the following variable `12345678901234567890`
and I want to create a text file named with the part `78901` from the middle of the variable `123456(78901)234567890`

How I can do that ?

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to mention what have you tried yet?

Answer (score 5):

```
string = '12345678901234567890'
name = string[6:11]
with open(name, 'w') as f:
    f.write("hello world")
```